# Time Complexity log(n) vs Big O (root n)

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Trying to analyze the below code snippet.
For the below code can the time complexity be Big O(log n)?. I am new to asymptotic analysis. In the tutorial it says its O( root n).

```
int p = 0;
for(int i =1;p<=n;i++){
p = p +i;
}
,,,
```

Comment: @templatetypedef Nope, it is square root. Though it's a bit odd way of doing it.

Comment: Damn, I explained why it was square root because I glanced over it and I thought you would actually show the square root implementation (ie `i += ++p;`). What you actually wrote is obviously `O(n)`.

Comment: Yea, I noticed that :(, it wasn't correct though. Hmmmm, is it sqrt(N) or linear hmmm

Comment: Sorry i posted the question wrong i re-edited it

Comment: It's the difference between addition and multiplication. Addition in this case gets you `O(sqrt(N))` more generally speaking it will give you some `O(kth root of N)`, depending on exactly how you set it up. If however, you use multiplication instead, now it's `O(log(N))`.

Comment: Main thing is work it backwards and you get roughly `N/2+N/4+N/8+N/16+...`

Comment: ThankYou @Nuclearman

Answer (score 4):

Variable `p` is going to take the successive values `1`, `1+2`, `1+2+3`, etc.

This sequence is called the sequence of **triangular numbers**; you can read more about it on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number) or [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A000217).

One thing to be noted is the formula:

```
1 + 2 + ... + i = i*(i+1)/2
```

Hence your code could be rewritten under the somewhat equivalent form:

```c
int p = 0;
for (int i = 1; p <= n; i++)
{
    p = i * (i + 1) / 2;
}
```

Or, getting rid of `p` entirely:

```c
for (int i = 1; (i - 1) * i / 2 <= n; i++)
{
}
```

Hence your code runs while `(i-1)*i <= 2n`. You can make the approximation `(i-1)*i ≈ i^2` to see that the loop runs for about `sqrt(2n)` operations.

If you are not satisfied with this approximation, you can solve for `i` the quadratic equation:

```
i^2 - i - 2n == 0
```

You will find that the loop runs while:

```
i <= (1 + sqrt(1 + 8n)) / 2 == 0.5 + sqrt(2n + 0.125)
```